# Just so lost... ViewSwitcher? Create an Activity then add to ViewSwitcher?

Tags: android, google-maps, viewswitcher

I'm new to Android and find it brutal (there seems to be an near infinite number of details and dependencies to remember).

Anywho, I got the TextSwitcher1 example app working, which uses ViewSwitcher. I'm assuming ViewSwitcher is the way to go, need to either display a map or a table, user can pick, and switch back and forth.

So I created my MapActivity in another application, seems to work. Next integrate into main app. So, call
        View v = findViewById(R.layout.mapview);
and then 
        mSwitcher.addView(v);
except "v" is null. Why? Do I create the activity? But I don't want to show it yet. Is there such a call as "create activity but hide it until needed"? Or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Did the answer help resolve your issue or are you still having problems getting your ViewSwitcher to work?  You can vote on the answer with the up/down arrows and mark an answer as "accepted" by clicking the checkbox if it helped you fix the problem!

Answer (score 1):

The `findViewById` function returns a `View` based on an ID resource (`R.id.something`) for whatever view you have loaded in your activity (using `setContentView(R.layout.main)`).  In your sample code, you're using a layout resource (`R.layout.mapview`).  You should inflate the XML file, which will return a `View` that you can use to add to the `ViewSwitcher`.

**Example Code:**

```
LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v = vi.inflate(R.layout.mapview, null);
mSwitcher.addView(v);
```

However, you should be able to define everything in your XML file and not have to manually add the pages to your `ViewSwitcher`.  Here's some example code on how to do that: http://inphamousdevelopment.wordpress.com/2010/10/11/using-a-viewswitcher-in-your-android-xml-layouts/